# Set up selenium server

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I am looking for a clear and concise tutorial on how to set up selenium server on a remote host and how to use it appropriately. I am still new to some of the set up and configurations of servers in general, and the selenium documentation seems worded in a way that is meant for a higher level of understanding. I have a few test case already set up on my local machine that work and now I want to figure out how to set it up remotely.

Comment: Did you try googling your question? There are tutorials out there. This isn't a programming question so it's not a good fit for SO. You should expect it to be closed soon.

Comment: @JeffC I have tried googling. I see now that this was the wrong place to post this. My apologies for that one

Answer (score 4):

**Server side:**

How to setup a server part, i.e. standalone server + webdriver (e.g. chromedriver).

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers

Standalone server has help:

```
java -jar <path_to>/selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -help
```

In fact there are 2 things: selenium-server (5+MB jar) and selenium-server-standalone (30+ MB jar).
https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.47/

As I understand selenium-server-standalone is enough for most tasks.
There is a topic about differences:

http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/selenium-rc-selenium-1-0/difference-between-selenium-server-and-selenium-server-standalone-!/

**Client side:**

Before you used some WebDriver interface implementation in your code.

Say, you could use ChromeDriver.
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html

Now you need to use RemoteWebDriver (implementation of WebDriver interface):
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html

Here are code snippets how to use RemoteWebDriver with various browser capabilities:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver

E.g. there could be such client code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// set some options
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
...
```

There is an explanation how it all works:

> RemoteWebDriver is an implementation class of the WebDriver interface
>   that a test script developer can use to execute their test scripts via
>   the RemoteWebDriver server on a remote machine.
>
> There are two parts to RemoteWebDriver: a server and a client
>
> The RemoteWebDriver server is a component that listens on a port for
>   various requests from a RemoteWebDriver client. Once it receives the
>   requests, it forwards them to any of the following: Firefox Driver, IE
>   Driver, or Chrome Driver, whichever is asked.
>
> The language-binding client libraries that serve as a RemoteWebDriver
>   client. The client, as it used to when executing tests locally,
>   translates your test script requests to JSON payload and sends them
>   across to the RemoteWebDriver server using the JSON wire protocol.
>
> When you execute your tests locally, the WebDriver client libraries
>   talk to your Firefox Driver, IE Driver, or Chrome Driver directly.
>   Now, when you try to execute your tests remotely, the WebDriver client
>   libraries talk to the RemoteWebDriver server and the server talks to
>   either the Firefox Driver, IE Driver, or Chrome Driver, whichever the
>   WebDriver client asks for.

It is copy/paste from:
http://www.myyesm.com/what-is-remotewebdriver/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already read through most of this and have written a few test cases already. What I really need is someone that goes through the set up, such as a video or step by step(with screenshots) tutorial. I am a pretty visual learning in most cases.

Comment: I also like visual learning. And constanlty downloading something from lynda.com, tutorialspoint etc. But in case of Selenium I did not find nothing worth to watch. Different languages have their features, I used javascript (oficial async selenium-webdriver), c# (using nuget module) and Java/Scala bindings. Most featured binding is for Java of course. I found nothing special to watch and even to read, with exception of some (quite poor) oficial documentation, StackOverflow. But documentations for language bindings are quite good. Also there are articles for different languages.